# How Does Google Hangout works in Safari if WebRTC does not work in safari

Tags: macos, safari, webrtc, google-hangouts

i am creating small application using webRTC and Nodejs.
After many R&D i found that webRTC seems to Work only in Chrome and Firefox and may be in opera higher versions.
and also webRTC is only technology which enables media using browser.
if is it so then what technology hangout is using , which also works well in safari?

Comment: Hangouts uses a custom plugin.

Comment: @Amber it means there are also other technologies available for browser which supports GettingMedia using Browser. is there any other plugin which allows me to open cam using browser just for safari.

Comment: There are different technologies and the plugin is probably custom(or has custom cases) for each OS. Are you not familiar with how plugins work? There is also the [plugin WebRTC4All](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc4all/) which may help you.

Comment: you have also temasys plugin which would cover some OS not covered by webrtc4all:
https://temasys.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TWPP/WebRTC+Plugins

Comment: @alex , thanks alot for your help ,will try the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC is already out there. Companies are using it for point-to-point and multipoint voice and video.

Google Hangout it doesn't use WebRTC, Google's VP8 codec, or even the standard H.264 codec. It uses an H.264/SVC (Scalable Video Coding) variant of it.

Comment: May you please provide instead of *Those who are in the know*  ?

Comment: Man, if you ain't in the know, then you just don't know, ya know?

Answer (score 1):

Google Hangouts uses Vidyo. Vidyo has a proprietary plugin which they likely re-brand for Google. I know because I had about a 1-2 hour call with Vidyo in May and they mentioned Google Hangouts among their customers.

http://info.vidyo.com/VidyoH2O-for-Google-Hangouts-ga.html

Vidyo has reasonably high priced servers which they offer for medical applications, but we needed their API which we found out was priced at $100,000+.

The conclusion: stay with WebRTC and restrict your user's browser. Safari is expected by some to offer support next year and there are signs that they are porting code from Google Chrome. http://bloggeek.me/webrtc-apple-or-microsoft/

Limited IE support is offered by various plugins if you have the time and/or money for that. ex. OpenTok